# Perspective 3D mapping for Top and Bottom view in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, 3d, perspective

Creating a 3D Extrude & Bevel of a package in Adobe Illustrator, how can I reach the same angle and perspective for Top View and Bottom View of the same object?

I can set the same Y and Z values, but how to adjust the X values for both, so that Top and Bottom objects look from the same angle?

Current view looks almost the same, but if to overlay both on each other, their sides are not aligned identical.

Values I set for Bottom View:

[image: Here are settings for the Bottom View I set]

Values I set for Top View:

[image: Here are settings for the Top View I set]

Here is the print-screen of the 'Map Art' 3D option in Illustrator. Isn't it a true 3D?
[image]

Comment: Its not 3d as such, its just a trick of making one projection. It has no 3d substance you can not edit it.

Comment: @joojaa No, actually it has! By 'Map Art...' option. I've added each side as symbol in a 3D Map.

Comment: For it to be considered truly 3D it must be able to manipulate its overall shape. Just because you can do the simplest possible 3d projection does not mean its 3d. You can not make any other shapes interact with it, Its just an simple transformation of 2 data points theres no general about it, If it was real 3d you could actually make more complex shapes out of it.

Comment: @joojaa Thanks for the explanation. I am not aware of this. So I guess Photoshop does the same thing as Illustrator?

Comment: Well Photoshop can display arbitrary 3d objects. But it is not really an editor it cant be used to model them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Illustrator's 3D effect is **not** "global". It is object-oriented. Meaning each instance of the effect is bound by the artwork it is applied to, not the artboard or "scene". The 3D effect is *completely ignorant* of any other objects with the 3D effect applied to them.

Illustrator is *never* the correct tool to use if you want *global* 3D settings. The *only* way to get "scene-like" 3D is though continual trial and error and "tweaking" of individual objects.

Or.. applying the effect at the *layer level*.

[image]

This means *everything* on that layer will have the same 3D Effect appearance applied to it.

But, when you apply the Effect to the **Layer** you can, and will, run into odd intersection issues....Note the **purple shapes** in the image below. They are in the correct stacking order, but still have this weird overlapping intersection issue.

[image]

My *guess* is that by rotating your object 180° the bounds changed, thus changing the positioning of the object-oriented 3D center.

You aren't doing anything "wrong". It is, and always has been, a limitation of the 3D effect in Adobe Illustrator. The 3D effect is a "patch" solution.... a quick thing added many years ago to half-heartedly satiate users asking for 3D. It has *never* been fully developed by the Adobe team. And in reality, has never even been improved, updated, or altered in 10+ years of AI development. All they've done over the years since adding it is make certain the UI matches the rest of the application.

If you are seeking to build 3D worlds or scenes, you are better served by moving to a *real* full-fledged 3D application such as Blender, Lightwave, Maya, etc.

Comment: Thats because its not 3D, not the way anybody sane would define it. Otherwise me drawing a camera projected image woudl be 3d. Illustrator si no more 3d than that.

Comment: @Scott Thanks for the support. But oh, you know what - actually I was just 'tweaking', but then get it. You should add + 180° to the X value to get the facing view. It works! Looks aligned.

Comment: Yeah `:)` it's all about "tweaking" the effects. I *wish* Adobe would make this more robust (like Adobe Dimensions used to be), but they don't seem to be interested in doing that. I have no idea what your edit and "true 3D" is asking @Olenia -- the Map art merely adds symbol artwork to faces and then distorts them around the object matching the 3D effect settings. It renders the art flat on surfaces, there will be no "depth map" like a real 3D app may provide.

Comment: Thanks @Scott. BTW, there is also an awful Map Art editor (when you add symbols on the surfaces) and it's hard to fit the image on the sides (The Top and Bottom fits good) Or maybe there is a way to set the exact size...

Comment: There are handles you can move which will "stretch" the artwork - just like the bounding box on non-3D objects. Again, not really sure what you are getting at.

Comment: I mean there is not a good control of it. For example, it's not 'snapping' to the border. Also, you can't use arrows to make small moves or shift to make aligned move.

Comment: Yeah.. it's not "real" 3D. It's the best Adobe came up with to try and satiate users asking for 3D features. It's a half-finished feature set that has not been improved in more the 10 years (if not 15). If you *really* want to build 3D objects or worlds, you should move to an *actual* 3D application such as Blender.

Comment: @Scott actually it isnt they actually had a decent 3d app that worked well but they scrapped it.

Comment: @joojaa Dimensions, at the time, was mediocre in terms of 3D. But today.. it actually does stuff no other 3D app will do (like keeping EVERYTHING vector, including type). It's actually an *excellent* "skeleton builder" which you can then save as .ai and open in Illustrator to add appearances. I actually have an old G4 that I can boot up *only for Dimensions*. It's my understanding Adobe *licensed* Dimensions and never really owned it.. so that's why it died. As stated, at the time, it was not the "best" 3D app out there and it wasn't gaining market-share.

Comment: @Scott no thats not true. all cad apps are 100% vector. Just not bezier but bsplines so conversion to adobe beziers is limited.

Comment: @Scott besides what the hell did adobe think that they could in a year or so make a app thats better than competition that had a 20 year headstart

Comment: @joojaa okay.. `;)` no 3D app I can use in conjunction with my other work without years of learning retains complete vectors the way Dimensions does `:)` I'm not a "3d guy". So, I can't devote years to learn more robust CAD apps `;)`  I just need minor things here or there, but it's always helpful to have those minor things in the most versatile format possible. Dimensions was/is a fantastic designer-oriented 3D app. They simply sold it as a "real 3D tool" when it's just "skeleton builder" for designers with Illustrator.

Comment: @Scott and thats why adobe screwed the thing up. PS dont call graphic designers designers. A lot of designers use more CAD apps all day long. Besides i could teach you to operate a parametric cad app in 5 afternoons no problem. I mean if you can use illustrators extrude you can use a cad app. Its even easier than using illsutrators extrude tool

Comment: Well come on over! :) -- and I mean "render as vectors" really. I can't get SketchUp, Blender, Maya, Lightwave, Strata3d, etc to *render* output as vectors for use in other apps. I'm sure more robust apps do that, but today Swift3D will do it somewhat, and Dimensions does it every time.

Comment: @Scott ill give you a holler when im around your quarter of the globe... ;)

Comment: @Scott as for vectors. sometimes in late 1990's CAD apps and DCC apps diverged. CAD software would build stuff out of nurbs patches and DCC apps would move over to making everything discrete because its easier to work with in free form way. Making it easier to sculpt etc... But CAD users actually wanted to develop surfaces liek you develop vector drawings because thats what they are doing. So they still have the vector tools. Unfortunately because CAD users want actual circles they can not use Beziers so conversion to accurate beziers is not possible. A cad app COULD be built on beziers

Comment: but is not done. Mainly because nurbs are superior. In all other aspects than dumping to PDF which is only in adobes interest.

Comment: Yes :) I absolutely realize my desired workflow is not the "norm" or possibly even "common". `:)` Which is why I simply keep that G4  with Dimension in the corner of the office. `:)`

Comment: @Scott im not so sure. People ask about normal CAD features all the time. Its a underserved market, and you can have it if you leave adobe land. Just that cad users have other priorities than you guys so...

Answer (score 1):

A little late, but maybe this is useful

[image]

To make top and bottom up versions (= otherwise the same projection, but 180 degrees differece in X-rotations) identical in Illustrator's 3D extrusion the shapes cannot be the same.  The other shape must be = the first shape as flipped around horizontal axis.

Here the X-rotations are 75 degrees and -105 degrees. The results are identical.

**About "does Illustrator have 3D?"** Illustrator can show how a rendered 3D extrusion or revolution surface would look out. But there's no accessible 3D surface. You cannot build proper combined pieces. An example:

[image]

In the left there's 2 extruded shapes. This is in a 3D CAD program. Illustrator would make the same pieces in few seconds.

In the middle the extrusion results are moved to overlap in 3D space. In Illustrator you cannot do this, because there's no accessible 3D pieces, you have only the 2D images of the rendered extrusion results. To make the same scene in Illustrator you must cut a hole to one of the shapes.

In the right there's a boolean difference of 3D shapes. It was 2 clicks in 3D CAD. Illustrator has nothing to make it in 3D, you must draw it.

**About vector rendering of a 3D scene:** It's sometimes useful to export the 3D scene as 2D vector wireframe and open it in Illustrator:

[image]

In this way it's well possible to get some tricky 2D drawing work done with very little effort. In Illustrator one can start from coloring or drawing the easy pieces.

**About artwork mapping**: It's a calculated 2D image how a 3D piece with mapped images would look out.

The mapping often is impossible because Illustrator divides surfaces to pieces. Only very simple shapes can be extruded or revolved so that you get the expected number of surfaces. Generally you may think you need 1...4 art symbols because you have 1...4 visible textured surfaces. But if the surfaces are divided, you must cover separately for example a dozen of them. Making all to fit is a nightmare.

Comment: Show also a difference of shaes its even more revealing.

Comment: You have got it.